# Finding the value of a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function. Then find the value of
>   $$\int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{it})\cos t~dt$$

Now I have dine the substitution $e^{it}=z$, which implies $dz=ie^{it}dt$, and hence the integral is reduced to $$\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)\cos\Big(\frac{\log z}{i}\Big)\frac{dz}{iz}$$
I know that I need to find out the poles and the corresponding residues of the integrand, but have no idea how to do so. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Try to rewrite $\cos(t)$ in terms of exponentials since this will make the suggested substitution easier to handle, namely $\cos t = \dfrac{e^{it} +e^{-it}}{2}$.

Comment: Right. That does it. Thanks